# BAT file: read output from exe

Tags: batch-file, stream

I launch some exe-file through the BAT-file and I want to save the output of this exe-file in the variable. I tryed this:

```
:: exe file writes some text into the output stream. I need
:: save this text in the variable.
SET value = call "%~dp0\sr.exe"
:: but variable has nothing:
ECHO value
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You use a `for /f` loop. See `for /?`. At it's most simple.

```
for /f "delims=" %A in ('dir') do echo %A
```

In batch `for` loops use `%%A` instead of `%A` interactively.